# see differences between branch and trunk [svn]

Tags: file, svn, branch, difference, svn-trunk

I just resolved a few conflicts in my branch manually and now, to confirm I got everything, I would like to see which files in my branch are different from the ones in trunk(before I even look at the difference in more detail). How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can do
`$ svn diff ^/trunk . | less` 
from my branch directory and watch for items tagged with `-`.